# start asterisk autometically when system got restarted

Tags: linux, service, centos, asterisk

I have installed asterisk 1.4 on linux centOS 6.2. and I have also made entry to start asterisk in **/etc/rc.local** as `/usr/bin/asterisk`.
but it did not worked. When the system starts, it shows that asterisk service has started but actually it's not working i.e. command `asterisk-vvvvr` does not work.

If I start the service manually after boot up the system, it works perfectly. can someone tell why asterisk is not working via **rc.local** file and I can start the asterisk automatically at system start up.

thanks in advance.
PS: I have already tried a lot of methods by googling but there is still problem.

Answer (score 4):

To get a proper init script and enable asterisk to start automatically on boot: change to the asterisk source directory and do this:

```
make config
chkconfig asterisk on
```

after that you can reboot.

Comment: Could you paste the output here? Are you installing from source?

Comment: I am not getting your point,
when I try to verbose it show error:
'Unable to connect to remote asterisk (does /var/run/asterisk.ctl exist?)'

Comment: please issue: "/etc/init.d/asterisk start" and post the output and say me if you are installing from source or other method.

Comment: it give me error as "-bash: /etc/init.d/asterisk: No such file or directory" but I can start the service asterisk as- by just type "asterisk"

Answer (score 1):

one subtle assumption here: to enable asterisk automatically on bootup, you have to be root and issue the command, ckhconfig (from olivecoder's steps)

$ sudo chkconfig asterisk on

- to verify that asterisk is indeed turned on, you should see something like

$ chkconfig |grep asterisk

asterisk        0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off

- to start the service w/o rebooting, you can try

$ sudo service asterisk start

- finally, to run the cli

$ sudo asterisk -rvvv

--- you should get something like this:

remus*CLI>

Answer (score 0):

Just goto asterisk directory where you have all asterisk binaries and run below command.

In my case my asterisk binaries are at.

`/usr/src/asterisk.`

`root@asterisk#` make config

Answer (score 0):

SELinux can also be a problem.

See [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800924/asterisk-unable-to-connect-to-remote-asterisk-does-var-run-asterisk-ctl-exis) here, which says:

If you have SELINUX enabled, it will prevent this file being created. You need to turn it off.

```
vi /etc/selinux/config
set SELINUX=disabled
reboot
```